# ASP Dictionary [Key, Array] pair

Tags: arrays, dictionary, vbscript, asp-classic

## **The Goal**

I'm trying to make a dictionary that stores a key (string) and a value (array) pair in ASP.

**The Problem:**

It seems that ASP is capable of storing the array as a value and furthermore capable of returning the value (at any point in the array), but it's not capable of updating the value?

**What I have**

```
Dim myDict
Set myDict=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I set the value with:

```
myDict.add someKey, someArray
```

I retrieve with:

```
myDict.Item(someKey)(somePosition)
```

However, this doesnt work:

```
myDict.Item(someKey)(somePosition) = "Hello"
```

Comment: @Kaf: Neither vb.net nor asp.net are appropriate here. Retagging.

Comment: try `dim a(0), b : a(0) = "one" : b = a: a(0) = "two": Response.Write(b(0))` arrays are copied, so changing one does not change the other - your assignment line affects a _copy_ not the original array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define a class instead of an array? Yes, ASP already supported classes to some extend.

```
Class MyType
   public Value1
   public Value2
   public Value3
End Class
```

You insert them into the dictionary like this:

```
dim myVal

Set myVal = new MyType
myVal.Value1 = 1
myVal.Value2 = "foo"
myVal.Value3 = "bar"

Set myDict.Item("key") = myVal
```

and modify like this:

```
myDict.Item("key").Value2 = "baz"
```

EDIT: to have a variable amount of values in each item:

```
Set myDict.Item("key") = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDict.Item("key").Item("var name") = "baz"
```

When I only need a variable list of Items, I use the Dictionary like this:

```
dim myDict
Set myDict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDict.Item(myDict.Count) = "foo"
myDict.Item(myDict.Count) = "bar"
myDict.Item(myDict.Count) = "baz"
```

... and get the values out in a simple loop:

```
for each myValue in myDict.Items
    Response.Write "Value is: " & myValue & "<br />"
next
```

Comment: What would I do if I need a variable amount of 'Value's in the class?

Comment: Well, you could include a dictionary in the class (more control) or directly use dictionaries as items in your myDict instead of MyType.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think thats going to work . To modify the value you need to delete the item and add a new one.

Comment: Is there a reason it allows storing and viewing the value but not modifying?

Comment: @CristianD . I am not sure. Maybe  Microsoft's way of keeping the data structure efficient.